# AutoHotkey ImageSearch failing to find matches

Tags: autohotkey, teamviewer

I have servers with an AutoHotkey script running on them, that I access via TeamViewer.

Sometimes AutoHotkey fails to match an ImageSearch even when the image it matches is captured from the displayed screen using Windows' Snipping Tool.

This only happens on some servers but not others. I have tried using ImageSearch *n shade variation, to no effect.

What could be causing the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can happen when TeamViewer is allowed to choose its own quality settings based on your connection to the server. If TeamViewer decides to use low quality settings for a connection, it will enable the Windows Basic Theme on the remote computer, potentially breaking AutoHotkey ImageSearch for some types of windows.

You can solve this by selecting custom settings in your own TeamViewer options when connecting to other clients.

- Go to Extras -> Options -> Remote Control
- Select Custom Settings from the Quality dropdown.
- Slide both sliders to the max (the right).
- Enable the Aero color scheme.

Disconnect from any open sessions and when you next connect, TeamViewer will not set the theme to Windows Basic.